# Interface to USB receipt printer in a point of sale system using PHP

Tags: php

I am currently writing a system in PHP that requires interface with a USB thermal receipt printer for a friend upon form submission. Currently I have read about interfacing with devices containing a parallel port but there has not been much detail on how I can use PHP to interface with a USB thermal receipt printer.

So far I have designed the receipt consisting of data that has been posted from the form. The next step would be to reproduce it on the thermal printer.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("PRN", "w"); // note 1 
fwrite($handle, 'text to printer'); // note 2 
fclose($handle); // note 3 
?>
```

This is what I found on http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Recipes/0399.php

> 1. Establish the connection with the receipt printer through PRN.
> 2. Writes to the receipt printer through the file handle.
> 3. Disconnect the printer.

It is rather vague? Any idea as to how it works?

Comment: What platform will this be on, Windows?

Comment: yes windows would be the platform it will run on

Comment: In theory, all USB devices should be accessible in exactly the same way. You should just have to loop through the list of connected USB devices until you find the right one. It shouldn't even need drivers if you intend to access it directly. Or alternatively, you can access it like any printer, which should also work. Of course, these are big shoulds. Most of the POS companies have no idea how to make hardware work right. :(

Comment: Any chance this is an open source project? My friend and I are looking into writing a custom stock management system in PHP & MySQL that would interface with a label printer. This could be very similar.

Comment: It's not just POS systems that have issues with thermal printers. I've had issues getting UPS & FedEx software to work properly with them as well. The hardest thing I've tried to do w/ them is network printing over a VPN Tunnel. That was interesting.

Comment: yes i would be willing to distribute the code freely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you are using PHP on a Win32 platform there is the [Printers PECL module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php) which can be installed.  So you can use the printer using the existing driver setup.

Depending on the printer in use it may be possible to use it directly if you know the command language, EPL/ZPL/etc., set the printer to raw mode and post the commands.

**Alternative:**

You can access the USB bus from PHP directly, if you setup the USB as a serial port and then use the [Direct IO Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dio.php) library `dio`.  Remembering to set serial options using the `mode` command before commencement.